# Select Box Option width Issue

Tags: html, css, angular-cli, bootstrap-4

Am facing Strange issue. Am having multiple select box in my project. Some of the select box option width exceeds select box width

Correct Dropdown:

[image: Screen Shot]

Incorrect Dropdown:

[image: Screen Shot]

Code:

```
<div class="form-group">
  <label id="lbl_crms_customer_add_sector_title">{{'CRMS.CUSTOMER.FORM_LABEL.SECTOR' | translate}}</label>   <span class="inactive_text"> *</span>
    <select id="lbl_crms_customer_add_sector_value" class="custom-select" #sector="ngModel" name="sector" [ngModel]="BasicInfoDetails.sector">
      <!-- <option selected value="">--</option> -->
      <option *ngFor="let sectorobj of sectorList" value="{{sectorobj}}">{{sectorobj}}</option>                            
    </select>
  <span><input-errors [control]="sector"></input-errors></span>
</div>
```

Note: The options are loaded dynamically from the server. Expecting Quickest answer from you guys :)

Comment: The code you provided does not show the whole "picture" i.e. this is just the code for the option group. There's other stuff that might be relevant. Post the code for the entire page. And post the output HTML, not the angular source code.

Comment: @WebDevBooster I dont think so. Since am following bootstrap 4 guidelines only. The issue is with the option word length. Refer the second Image

Comment: So, you don't really want to get a solution. OK then!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a strange behavior at all. It's how it is intended to work.

Options cannot be wrapped inside a select menu. The `select` element by default occupies the most space available to accommodate the largest `option` width **plus** the dropdown arrow with. If the *container* (not browser in this case) width is not enough to accommodate the full option width + dropdown arrow, ellipsis (...) appears in the `select` element.

Here are your options:

- Constraint the `select` width using pixels. However, the options window will take up as much width as possible within the browser to show the full option content. If it exceeds browser width then ellipsis (...) appear at the end of each option.
- Skip the native select and replace it with a custom-tailored dropdown menu, that can be restricted using CSS styling, or you can allow the content to wrap.

Answer (score 1):

In my previous project even I had the same requirement. I used http://gregfranko.com/jquery.selectBoxIt.js/ plugin to fix it.

Here is a demo **[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/ab45ndkn/)**

Its a JQuery plugin.

```
$(function() {

  $("#testselectset").selectBoxIt({
    theme: "default",
    defaultText: "Make a selection...",
    autoWidth: false
  });
  $("#testselectset").change(function() {
    alert("You selected: " + this.value + " from the Selectboxit plugin");
  });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

They may exceed because the second  select option has more content in one row.
 By default the size of the  element is depend on the size of the largest  text

Comment: Yes am aware of it. But my requirement is to fix the option width to the select box width.

Answer (score -1):

```
Chech this code

    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Increase Select Box Size on Focus</title>
<style type="text/css">
    select {
        width: 150px;
        margin: 10px;
    }
    select:focus {
        min-width: 150px;
        width: auto;
    }    
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <form>
        <select>
            <option>Choose</option>
            <option>This option is large</option>
            <option>This option is very large</option>
            <option>This option is very very large</option>
            <option>This option is very very very large</option>
        </select>
        <select>
            <option>Choose</option>
            <option>This option is large</option>
            <option>This option is very large</option>
            <option>This option is very very large</option>
            <option>This option is very very very large</option>
        </select>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This won't control the <option> width